# What is needed to control 200 LED's from an Arduino

Tags: arduino, led, 74hc595

I am new to Arduino and want to use two 74HC595 shift registers to control 200 leds. What will I need to consider / get to make this possible?

These are your average starter LED's.

Thank you!

Comment: just an alternate way to drive the LEDs http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/tlc5921.html instead of the 74xx595

Answer (score 4):

With Charlieplexing, you can directly drive n*(n-1) LEDs from n pins. This means 210 LEDs from 15 pins. This can be done with a regular Arduino Uno if you use some of the analog pins as output.

If you need different colors with different resistors, you have to do some smart segmenting. You also have to think about the time multiplex, high pulse current. This is probably easier if you know you will only have a few leds on at each time.

See application here: http://www.evilmadscientist.com/article.php/bulbdial3

Answer (score 2):

The only thing to consider is time to shift out your data. But if you would build 8 parallel shiftout streams, you can do that 8 times faster :-)

Also, make sure to provide sufficient power to all these 595's, total power consumption might get quite significant.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to control 64 (8<sup>2</sup>) LEDs from your 2 8-bit registers would be to set up a matrix of LEDs (the matrix is simply how the circuit is electrically, you could place them wherever (in a line, circle...), though you will have a great deal of wiring.

Your circuit would then connect a few LEDs to ground, and power whichever ones among them it needs.  A few milliseconds later, you connect a different set of LEDs to ground, and repeat, very quickly.

Among the Arduino pages there is [one that discusses this](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/DirectDriveLEDMatrix).  It doesn't include 595's, as they will slow it down a bit, but it's simple enough to combine the ideas.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you only have 2 8-bit ports, then you can only control 64 individual LEDs... (unless you control them in groups of 4)

Comment: @BG100, yeah, that's right, I was calculating 8**2 as 256 for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your application.  Do you want individual control of each led?  What is your refresh rate.  How bright do you need the led's..... Can you give some more info?